# helloworld of arcgis sdk sample is not running

Tags: android, arcgis

i am new to arcgis sdk and  imported the hello world sample to my workspace and cleand and builed it and there were no errors.
But when i run it it shows me "unfortunatiely helloworld stoped working".

Following output in my logcat:

```
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.arcgis.android.samples.maps.helloworld/com.arcgis.android.samples.maps.helloworld.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.arcgis.android.samples.maps.helloworld.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.arcgis.android.samples.maps.helloworld-2.apk
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.arcgis.android.samples.maps.helloworld.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.arcgis.android.samples.maps.helloworld-2.apk
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
12-24 16:24:43.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You import it in Eclipse or Studio. Take a closer look it has Gradle files

Comment: to eclipse,and can u tell me what  Gradle files is and how its related to my question.thanks

Comment: If u observe the project structure it's little different than usual project structure of android project. Eclipse uses ant to build the project, while android studio uses the gradle. For now u just create Blank project in Eclipse and copy files from sdk and build. It will work.

Comment: so can u take a look at my log cat and tell me y its stops running as soon as i launched it.thanks